# Is Expandable ListView Expanded?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

What is the code for checking if the Expandable ListView is in the expanded state? Does any method exist that gives a true or false value depending upon the opened or closed state of an Expandable ListView.
This may seem like an easy question, but I've searched many places and could not find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the android documentation it says isGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

It looks as though each row can be expanded and these are know as groups. Therefore, can only find out if any one group is expanded. To know if all are you would need to loop through each and run this function.

Comment: If he doesn't know the position he could also set expand and collapse listeners and work from that data if there are expanded groups or not. But looping would probably be better especially if there are not many groups.

Comment: Thanks for those quick solutions! In my case, I have a fixed number of groups - 6. So is it better to use a for loop, or are just if's enough?

Comment: I would generally go for a for loop then if it does expand in size it would still work. Just makes sure it doesn't cause issues in the future